# ms-access form with login and password. Don't proceed until both are completed

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

the guy from the Baptism database is here again.
In Visual Studio it's easy but here I don't get it done.
I have form with two textboxes: login and password.
I have a button to check the info
Both must be completed before I check if they can use the database.
After the on_click command I do have the following code:

```
Private Sub KValidatie_Click()
Dim ok As Boolean
    
    ok = False
    
    Do While Not ok
        MsgBox ("Both fields must be completed")
        Me.FLogin.SetFocus
    Loop
    'here follows code that is working

End Sub
```

But this way I come in an endless loop and I can't fill in those fields anymore.

Does anyone has a simple solution for this problem

I searched the internet for a solution, but what I find is about msgboxes or it's about fields in the tables itself.
I only have to check for the right persons to enter in to see what their admissions are.
I tried the .control thing, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a loop. Use If Then Else.

```
If IsNull(box1 + box2) Then
    MsgBox "Both fields must be completed"
    Me.FLogin.SetFocus
Else
'continue with code
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking each control individually so you can set the focus to the correct control if the value has not been provided. It's poor practice to set the focus to the username, when the password is missing.

Also, `DoCmd.Close` is incomplete, you need to set the close parameters.

```
Private Sub KValidatie_Click()

    'Username
    With Me.FLogin
        If IsNull(.Value) Then
            .SetFocus
            MsgBox "The username is required."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    'Password
    With Me.FPaswoord
        If IsNull(.Value) Then
            .SetFocus
            MsgBox "The password is required."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    'Reaching this point means both username and password were supplied.
    evaluatie ' check if Login and password are oké
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSavePrompt

End Sub
```

Lastly, `evaluatie` should be a function returning `true/false` and close the form only when the function returns true (which means the credentials were successfully evaluated).